# How to get FCM notifications working while app is in background (ios)?

Tags: ios, firebase, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

I am using Firebase with my IOS app and I am trying to set up push notifications.

Currently I am able to receive push notifications while my app is in the foreground however when I put it in the background I am not able to receive any.

In my app capabilities I enabled push notifications as well as remote notifications in the background modes section.

I am currently using Postman to send the following POST request:

```
https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send

Content-Type:application/json
Authorization:key=<my_server_key>

{   "to" : "token_id",
    "priority":"high",
    "data":{  
      "title":"mytitle",
      "body":"mybody",
      "url":"myurl"
   },
   "notification":{  
      "title":"mytitle",
      "body":"mybody",
      "content_available": true
   }
}
```

After I send the request I receive a status of 200 and the following response:

```
{
  "multicast_id": 7920502412622407470,
  "success": 1,
  "failure": 0,
  "canonical_ids": 0,
  "results": [
   {
      "message_id": "0:1469561276461379%345a0fe5f9fd7ecd"
    }
  ]
}
```

I followed these two guides to set up sending on receiving messages:

https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/ios/client#receive_messages_through_messaging

https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/ios/certs

Here is my AppDelegate file:

**AppDelegate.swift**

```
@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

    var window: UIWindow?

    override init(){
        // Configure Firebase
        FIRApp.configure()
        // Mantain data offline (persists state)
        FIRDatabase.database().persistenceEnabled = true
    }

    func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {
        // Register for remote notifications
        if #available(iOS 8.0, *) {
            // [START register_for_notifications]
            let settings: UIUserNotificationSettings = UIUserNotificationSettings(forTypes: [.Alert, .Badge, .Sound], categories: nil)
            application.registerUserNotificationSettings(settings)
            application.registerForRemoteNotifications()
            // [END register_for_notifications]
        } else {
            // Fallback
            let types: UIRemoteNotificationType = [.Alert, .Badge, .Sound]
            application.registerForRemoteNotificationTypes(types)
        }

        // Add observer for InstanceID token refresh callback.
        NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: #selector(self.tokenRefreshNotification), name: kFIRInstanceIDTokenRefreshNotification, object: nil)


        // Override point for customization after application launch
        return FBSDKApplicationDelegate.sharedInstance().application(application, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: launchOptions)
    }

    func application(application: UIApplication, didRegisterUserNotificationSettings notificationSettings: UIUserNotificationSettings) {
        if notificationSettings.types != .None {
            application.registerForRemoteNotifications()
        }
    }

    func application(application: UIApplication, didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken deviceToken: NSData) {
        let refreshedToken = FIRInstanceID.instanceID().token()!
        print("InstanceID token:", refreshedToken)
    }

    func application(application: UIApplication, didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError error: NSError) {
        print("Failed to register:", error)
    }

    func application(application: UIApplication, openURL url: NSURL,
                             sourceApplication: String?,
                             annotation: AnyObject) -> Bool {

        return FBSDKApplicationDelegate.sharedInstance().application(
            application,
            openURL: url,
            sourceApplication: sourceApplication,
            annotation: annotation)
    }

    func application(application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [NSObject : AnyObject],
                     fetchCompletionHandler completionHandler: (UIBackgroundFetchResult) -> Void) {

        FIRMessaging.messaging().appDidReceiveMessage(userInfo)
        // Print full message.
        print("%@", userInfo)
    }

    func tokenRefreshNotification(notification: NSNotification) {
        let refreshedToken = FIRInstanceID.instanceID().token()!
        print("InstanceID token: \(refreshedToken)")

        // Connect to FCM since connection may have failed when attempted before having a token.
        connectToFcm()
    }

    func connectToFcm() {
        FIRMessaging.messaging().connectWithCompletion { (error) in
            if (error != nil) {
                print("Unable to connect with FCM. \(error)")
            } else {
                print("Connected to FCM.")
            }
        }
    }

    func applicationWillResignActive(application: UIApplication) {
        // Sent when the application is about to move from active to inactive state. This can occur for certain types of temporary interruptions (such as an incoming phone call or SMS message) or when the user quits the application and it begins the transition to the background state.
        // Use this method to pause ongoing tasks, disable timers, and throttle down OpenGL ES frame rates. Games should use this method to pause the game.
    }

    func applicationDidEnterBackground(application: UIApplication) {
        // Use this method to release shared resources, save user data, invalidate timers, and store enough application state information to restore your application to its current state in case it is terminated later.
        // If your application supports background execution, this method is called instead of applicationWillTerminate: when the user quits.
        FIRMessaging.messaging().disconnect()
        print("Disconnected from FCM.")
    }

    func applicationWillEnterForeground(application: UIApplication) {
        // Called as part of the transition from the background to the active state; here you can undo many of the changes made on entering the background.
    }

    func applicationDidBecomeActive(application: UIApplication) {
        // Restart any tasks that were paused (or not yet started) while the application was inactive. If the application was previously in the background, optionally refresh the user interface.
        FBSDKAppEvents.activateApp()
        connectToFcm()
    }

    func applicationWillTerminate(application: UIApplication) {
        // Called when the application is about to terminate. Save data if appropriate. See also applicationDidEnterBackground:.
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to check "Remote notifications" in your Xcode project configuration file. Look at
[this screeenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CWXNl.png)

Although the message won't be delivered if your app is in background. Eg. If you kill it or hasn't been launched yet :(